# R: Subset rows with non NA values dplyr

Tags: r, select, dplyr, na

I have this type of data frame

```
DF
ID    V1         V2    V3
1     AXETINE    NA    2011
2     XOROX      INJ   NA
3     HERPESIN   NA    NA
4     ZOVIRAX    INJ   2015
```

and I would like to get this:

```
DF
ID    V1         V2    V3
1     AXETINE    NA    2011
4     ZOVIRAX    INJ   2015
```

I would like to get only rows with non NA values in V3

I have tried:

```
DF %>% na.omit(V3)
```

and

```
DF %>% select(!is.na(V3))
```

But this error occurs

> Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.

I found a base R solution, but is there a dplyr one?

Comment: You need `filter(!is.na(V3))` instead of `select()`.

Comment: `select` has to do with the columns. you need to use `filter` as already mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% filter(!is.na(V3))
```